# How to get URL image as Base64 image data for zipping using JSZip

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, base64

I am working on a web project using Node.js, HTML5, CSS5 and Jquery. I need to get an image from the server using a URL (eg. address.com/image.jpg) as Base64 image data for zipping using JSZip.

Can anyone tell me how to get the url image as base64 image data? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all files regardless whether they are images or not.

1) read your file into a buffer.
2) call `toString('base64')` on that buffer.

You can use filters to do that for any image url, or you can have a separate endpoint to handle base64 conversions.

Comment: Thank you! I found the answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

Comment: Oh i thought you wanted to convert it on the server side. Anyways, cheers..

Comment: So sorry, I probably could make it clearer. Thank you so much!